# IndexedDB -- Need an tool

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blazor, indexeddb

I have a PWA that saves data locally to indexedDb. Works fine.  But I feel hampered by a lack of an editor like SSMS for SqlServer.  To make a small change, I have to edit code.

I wondered if anyone had seen any tools (it looks like a chrome extension could do it) that might be useful?  I'm working with Blazor (have a lot of Vue.js and Vanilla JS experience, but Blazor is just more productive).....so a component I could add to my application would be a major bonus!!

Prefer to avoid homebrew if someone has something already.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> so a component I could add to my application would be a major bonus

To inspect and make changes directly in the browser have a look at the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/indexeddb).

Comment: A UI component. You have to write code to make the changes.  

I use Chrom Dev Tools daily -- and its fine for inspecting the data but in order to make any changes you have to write code. Its a dozen lines of JS to modify a field.  And if I wanted something someone else could use, asking them to edit code is a non-starter.